# why Digester is generating different hash code for same message, code and iteration

Tags: java, encryption, hash

i have write a hash code covert method in spring security. In that method, i will save salt value and iteration size in database. when user login with plain password next time i will use salt value and iteration from database and digest the password. But this method is generation different hash code even if the salt and iteration value are same.

```
public Administrator encryptDigestCode(Administrator administrator) {
    StandardStringDigester digester = new StandardStringDigester();
    Administrator admin = new Administrator();
    digester.setAlgorithm("SHA-256");
    digester.setStringOutputType("base64");
    Random ran = new Random();
    int iterate = ran.nextInt(1000);
    digester.setIterations(iterate);
    RandomSaltGenerator ram = new RandomSaltGenerator();
    byte[] salt = ram.generateSalt(10);
    String pass = new String(salt) + administrator.getHashedPassword();
    String encryptedPassword = digester.digest(pass);
    if (digester.matches(administrator.getHashedPassword(),
            encryptedPassword)) {
        admin.setLoginDetail(new LoginDetail());
        admin.getLoginDetail().setSalt(new String(ram.generateSalt(10)));
        admin.getLoginDetail().setHashingCycle(iterate);
        admin.setUserName(administrator.getUsername());
        admin.setSesamiagreementno(administrator.getSesamiagreementno());
        admin.setHashedPassword(encryptedPassword);
    } else {
        admin.setLoginDetail(null);
        admin.setHashedPassword(null);
        admin.setUserName(null);
    }
    return admin;
}
```

how should i do? any code or site for reference. thanks

Comment: You will have to post the real code, not some code that simply generates a new random salt each time it is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you use a Random Salt. -- Then of course the hash is always different.

---

And there is a second random value

```
Random ran = new Random();
int iterate = ran.nextInt(1000);
digester.setIterations(iterate);
```

I would expect that this also influent the result. So if you do not have the luck go get the same random value twice, hash is different.

Comment: hi ralph, yes i use random salt.but that value will be save in database for next time when user login. i will get that salt value in database and add with the plain password user enter then do digest. but the hash code i save in database is different with when i generate second time

Comment: @sudo: There is a second random value - see my extended answer.  BTW I have the feeling that there is some mistake: The salt needs to be add to the password before the hash is calulated - but may i do not understand the code correct

Answer (score 0):

The line

`admin.getLoginDetail().setSalt(new String(ram.generateSalt(10)));`

is wrong. First, it generates a new random salt and puts it into the database rather
than using the variable salt. I.e. you call generateSalt twice: the first result is used to hash the password and the second result is stored in the database. Secondly, it converts a random array of bytes into a string.
Unless you are sure that these bytes correspond to printable characters you should e.g. use a base64 encoding here (and of course the appropriate decoding, whenever necessary).

Also using a random integer for the number of iterations is not such a great idea. The number of iterations should make a brute force attack against a single target expensive to compute. If you use a random number here, then an attacker might just try to find the user with the lowest iteration count and start attacking this password.